# What does 'underwritten" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

I am asking about the meaning of 'underwritten' in the following sentence?
*The film received generally positive reviews from critics, with praise for its visual effects and action sequences, but with criticism towards its underwritten human characters.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like nonstandard or specialist usage. Possibly a typo.

Comment: It looks like nonstandard or specialist usage.

Comment: Personally I take it to mean that the human characters are not sufficiently developed or fleshed out (ie. they seem “two dimensional”) - the writers haven’t written enough about (ie they have “underwritten”) those characters.  But as Lawrence says, it’s either a specialist use of the word by filmmakers, or at least a non-standard use of it.  Perhaps others familiar with the film industry can confirm.

Comment: pbasdf is correct; here's a reference https://writershelpingwriters.net/2015/11/the-fatal-flaw-of-underwriting/

Answer (score 2):

I might prefer to see 'under-written' there, to avoid confusion with 'underwritten' as used in the insurance business. It's the kind of word familiar to movie buffs and people who read reviews in e.g. *Variety*:

> "With multiple authors but no clear voice, the clumsy “Mulan” script
> often puts plot above character, depriving Mulan of a robust
> personality. Defined by her determination, she mostly keeps to
> herself, which deprives her of meaningful human relationships during
> the mid-section of the film. **Underwritten** as she is, Mulan is handily
> upstaged by Xianniang (Gong Li), a powerful sorceress invented for the
> film who gives Mulan a strong female adversary. "

[Mulan (*Variety* review)](https://variety.com/2020/film/reviews/mulan-review-live-action-adaptation-1234758090/)